# Proof verification : $f$ is continuous at $c$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ has zero-jump at $c$ for increasing $f$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, continuity, monotone-functions

**The Problem :** Let $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and $f : J \to \mathbb{R}$ be increasing. Define the jump at the point $c$ as follows:

$j_f(c)=\lim_{x \to c+}f(x)-\lim_{x \to c-}f(x)$ if $c \in J$ is not an end-point of $J.$

$j_f(c)=\lim_{x \to c+}f(x)-f(c)$ if $c \in J$ is the left end-point of $J.$

$j_f(c)=f(c)-\lim_{x \to c-}f(x)$ if $c \in J$ is the right end-point of $J.$

To show that $f$ is continuous at $c \in J$ *iff* $j_f(c)=0.$

**I'm attaching my solution (A few pieces of argument is marked as *informal* as they are similar to the previous line of argument and hence not elaborated). Please notify if there's any gap/flaws in the arguments, also whether it could be made shorter by any other technique. Any comment/suggestion regarding this proof, or maybe in general context (style of proof-writing etc), would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.**

**My Solution :**

**$(\Rightarrow)$ part :** Suppose $c$ is not an end-point of $J$. Given $f$ is continuous at $c.$ Fix $\epsilon > 0.$ Then $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta) \cap J \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon.$ Hence $$x \in (c-\delta,c) \cap J \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon \tag 1$$
$$x \in (c,c+\delta) \cap J \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon \tag 2$$ Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we conclude from $(1)$ that $\lim_{x \to c-}f(x)=f(c)$ and from $(2)$ that $\lim_{x \to c+}f(x)=f(c).$ Hence $j_f(c)=\lim_{x \to c+}f(x)-\lim_{x \to c-}f(x)=f(c)-f(c)=0.$

Now suppose $c$ is the left end-point of $J$. Given $f$ is continuous at $c.$ Then $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta) \cap J = [c,c+\delta) \cap J \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon.$ So, $x \in (c,c+\delta) \cap J \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon.$ Thus $\lim_{x \to c+}f(x)=f(c),$ and hence $j_f(c)=0.$

*Informal : Similarly, if $c$ is the right-end point of $J,$ we obtain $j_f(c)=0.$*

*Note* : We did not need the fact that $f$ is an increasing function to establish this side of the equivalence.

**$(\Leftarrow)$ part :** Suppose $c$ is not an end-point of $J.$ Now $j_f(c)=0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x \to c-}f(x)=\lim_{x \to c+}f(x)=l$ $($let$).$ Thus $\exists \delta_1>0$ and $\delta_2>0$ such that

$$x \in (c-\delta_1, c) \cap J \setminus \{c\} \Rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$$
$$x \in (c, c+\delta_2) \cap J \setminus \{c\} \Rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$$
Let $\delta=min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}>0$. Then
$$x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta) \cap J \setminus \{c\} \Rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\epsilon \tag 3$$

Claim : $l=f(c).$

We prove the claim by contradiction. First we assume $l<f(c).$ Choose $\epsilon = \frac{f(c)-l}{2}>0.$ Then $\exists \delta_3>0$ such that
$x \in (c-\delta_3,c+\delta_3) \cap J \setminus \{c\} \Rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\epsilon,$ in particular $f(c+\frac{\delta_3}{2})<l+\epsilon=\frac{l+f(c)}{2}<f(c),$ which is a contradiction since $f$ is increasing.

*Informal : If otherwise, let $l>f(c),$ we similarly choose $\epsilon=\frac{l-f(c)}{2}>0$ and a corresponding $\delta_4>0.$ Check that $f(c-\frac{\delta_4}{2})>f(c),$ contradicting the fact that $f$ is increasing.*

Hence we conclude (by trichotomy law of real numbers) that $l=f(c).$ Now, putting $l=f(c)$ in $(3)$ and noting that $x=c \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|=0<\epsilon,$ we obtain

$$x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta) \cap J \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon \tag 4$$

Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $f$ is continuous at $c.$

Now suppose $c$ is the left end-point of $J.$ Then $j_f(c)=0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x \to c+}f(x)=f(c),$ i.e. given $\epsilon>0, \exists \delta > 0,$ such that $x \in (c, c+\delta) \cap J \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon.$ At $x=c,$ obviously $|f(x)-f(c)|=0<\epsilon.$ Thus $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta) \cap J \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon,$ and hence $f$ is continuous at $c.$

*Informal : Similarly if $c$ is the right end-point of $J,$ we have $j_f(c)=0 \Rightarrow$ $f$ is continuous at $c.$*

This completes the proof. $\square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems correct!
Also You could simply say since $f$ is increasing then 
$$L(c):= \lim_{x \to c-}f(x) \leq f(c) \leq \lim_{x \to c+}f(x)=R(c)  $$
(for end points one of these two limit is same as $f(c)$)
Now, under the assumption that $f$ is increasing 
$$j_f(c)=0  \quad \text{iff}  \quad L(c)=R(c)=f(c) \quad \text{iff} \quad\text{   f is continuous at $c$}$$